# Python: How to avoid recursion with monkey patching

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to apply a monkey patching to fix an issue. However, the problem is it's creating recursion.

**Library Code**

base_hook.py

```
class BaseHook(object):
    def __init__(self, source):
        pass
```

ssh_hook.py

```py
class SSHHook(BaseHook):
    def __init__(self, source, timeout=10):
        super(SSHHook, self).__init__(source)

    def get_conn(self):
        print("SSH Hook")
```

**Monkey Patching**

```py
class CustomSSHHook(SSHHook):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomSSHHook, self).__init__(
            source="abc",
            timeout=20
        )

    def get_conn(self):
        try:
            print("custom ssh Hook")
            return super(CustomSSHHook, self).get_conn()
        except Exception as e:
            print("retry mechanism")
            raise e
```

**init**.py

```py
print "running monkey patching ssh hook get_conn"
ssh_hook.SSHHook = custom_ssh_hook.CustomSSHHook
# ssh_hook.SSHHook.get_conn = custom_ssh_hook.CustomSSHHook.get_conn
print "completed monkey patching ssh hook get_conn"
```

**Error**

```
  File "ssh_hook.py", line 5, in __init__
    super(SSHHook, self).__init__()
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: How are you patching?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon updated the question.

Comment: If you can at least read and are allowed to reuse the code of "SSHHook" then do that and create modified "CustomSSHHook" with same code as "SSHHook" where no modification needed which would then derive from "BaseHook" directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add custom `init` method:

```
class CustomSSHHook(SSHHook):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SSHHook, self).__init__()
```

You can detect recursion by addition new variable to your class, do increment of it and check the value.

*In general you don't need to specify arguments for `super` in python3

Comment: I can't do that. as I can't modify `SSHHook`. it's a library code. And that's where the recursion is happening.

Comment: @GaurangShah You need to modify `CustomSSHHook`, not `SSHHook`

Comment: sorry, not able to get you. recursion is happenign inside `SSHHook` class. How can I control that using `CustomSSHHook` class ?

Comment: Firstly, just try the to add init method. It can solve your issue

Comment: I overlooked the solution. it's working with my sample code.. However it's still failing with my orignal code. need to debug more.

Comment: Maybe somewhere library use direct import `from ssh_hook import SSHHook`. In this case maybe the only solution would be to fork and patch the library. Or you can discuss with developers of this library the way to customize your hook

Comment: if I using `SSHHook` then it calls the constructor of `BaseHoook` which is causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the original class (before the monkey patch) in a variable and use that in instead of super():

```
OriginalSSHHook = SSHHook
class CustomSSHHook(SSHHook):
    def get_conn(self):
        try:
            print("custom ssh Hook")
            return OriginalSSHHook.get_conn(self)
        except Exception as e:
            print("retry mechanism")
            raise e
```

Comment: could you please take a look at the code again, I have made some updates. I have to call parent class `init` and that's where all the recursion is occuring.